# What is Bond's first line in Spectre?

Tags: dialogue, james-bond, spectre

At the beginning of the new James Bond film, [*Spectre*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2379713/) (2015), we see Bond and an anonymous girl go into a hotel room.  Right at it looks like they're about to begin a romantic interlude, he turns to go.  She asks where he's going, and he says... something brief that I couldn't quite catch, and then he heads off to do spy stuff and get the plot rolling.

What was Bond's first line?

Comment: There was something about coming back soon. I remember thinking at the end of the film that she was probably still waiting.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2000/49).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line is;

"...Won't be long", before walking out onto the terrace/rooftop.

Comment: I just watched it on Friday and was paying extra-special-super-close attention because of this question...and I still couldn't make it out.